# How to change the header and footer in the Section Breaks Next Page using OpenXML?

Tags: ms-word, openxml, sections

I have a word document file in which I added a Section Break of Next Page, now I want to change the header and footer of that page.

Scenario of example, I have a doc file which has four pages with headers and footers and added fifth page in the section break next page, I want to change the header and footer of the fifth page only. This is achievable manually by deselecting the Link to Previous button in the Word Application but I don't know how to change it using XML?

My code that adds the new page in the section breaks is:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string path = @"C:\sample.docx";
        string strtxt = "Hello This is done by programmatically";      

       OpenAndAddTextToWordDocument(path,strtxt);
    }
    public static void OpenAndAddTextToWordDocument(string filepath, string txt)
    {

        using (DocX document = DocX.Load(@"C:\Riyaz\sample.docx"))
        {            
            document.InsertSectionPageBreak();
            Paragraph p1 = document.InsertParagraph();
            p1.Append("This is new section");
            document.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help.